# how to access to one element of a json files?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I don't know how to access to element of my JSON files. How should I do ?

Here is the JSON file : https://ingrwf08-1d60c.firebaseio.com/Villes.json

```
{
   "-MLMyLHb8T5UKRdJLG17": {
      "covid_incidence":"2494",
      "creation":"1666",
      "espaces_verts":"2",
      "famille":"non",
      "favoris":"111",
      "gare":"on",
      "hotels":"80",
      "latitude":"50.4099",
      "legend_image":"Place Verte de la Ville basse",
      "longitude":"4.4442",
      "musees":"15",
      "nom":"charleroi",
      "population":"425000",
      "province":"0",
      "superficie":"554.55",
      "theme":"city",
      "url_image":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ingrwf08-1d60c.appspot.com/o/charleroi.jpg?alt=media"
   },
   ...
}
```

In my `.js` I access to the JSON via *. get like this but i don't know how to access to a specific key.

For example retrieve   the value : `2494` of the key `covid_incidence`

```
function callBck(data) {
    console.log(data); //works to show the .json files but i dont know how to access to a specific key like "creation"
}

var url = "https://ingrwf08-1d60c.firebaseio.com/Villes.json";

$.get(url, callBck);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1-1 (If you know the key)

```
 $.get("https://ingrwf08-1d60c.firebaseio.com/Villes.json", function(response){
    console.log(response['-MLMzwIiiRy_YvvdmqFB']['covid_incidence'])
});
```

Method 1-2

```
$.get("https://ingrwf08-1d60c.firebaseio.com/Villes.json", function(response){
    $.each(response, function(key, val) {
        if(key=='-MLMzwIiiRy_YvvdmqFB'){
           console.log(val['covid_incidence']);
        }
    });
});
```

Method 2 (If you want to get 2nd element)

```
$.get("https://ingrwf08-1d60c.firebaseio.com/Villes.json", function(response){
    var i=1;
    $.each(response, function(key, val) {
        if(i==2){
           console.log(val['covid_incidence']);
        }
        i++;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple **JSON** data you can iterate it by key:

```js
var url ="https://ingrwf08-1d60c.firebaseio.com/Villes.json";

$.get(url, callBck);

function callBck (data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        console.log(val['covid_incidence']);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: many thanks for your reply . so it return all the value 'covid_incidence' but how can i acess only the second one?  2565 .